# "Phone calls", "Media audio", "Contact sharing" option missing in Bluetooth settings

Tags: samsung, settings, bluetooth

I have a Samsung phone. "Phone calls", "Media audio", "Contact sharing" options are missing in Bluetooth settings. There's only a toggle for "Audio".

[image]

Any idea why "use for" option is missing?

Comment: It'd be very helpful if you could add in your post your smartphone's model.

Comment: Looks like you're connecting to [a wireless speaker](https://www.jbl.com/bluetooth-speakers/GO+3-.html). Why would it have access to phone calls, media audio, and contact sharing though?

Comment: To elaborate on Andrew T.'s comment, these settings are device-dependent. Are you puzzled that they aren't available because they usually would be with this particular device, or because you've seen them for other devices? If the latter, then it's probably because those aren't settings for this device. If the former, is it perhaps paired with another phone? If you pair a Bluetooth device with multiple phones, some options might be available on only the first phone connected (e.g. if you pair a Plantronics headset with two phones, both have "Audio" but only one has "Media").